# Maven compile/install changes JSP content

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat, war

I have a remote git repository from which a WAR is built. The process is:

**git push to remote

git clone on remote

mvn clean

mvn install**

The problem is that content in one of the JSP files changes during the mvn install that creates the WAR. This is what the cloned source JSP snippet looks like:

```
        <c:forEach items="${agents}" var="agent">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${agent.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${agent.phone}"/></td>
                <td><a href="${newMonthlyUrl}/${agent.guid}"><i class="icon-plus"></i> New Monthly</a></td>
                <td><a href="${editUrl}/${agent.guid}"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="${deleteUrl}/${agent.guid}"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

But in the target WAR, the ${agent.name} is wiped out, and is empty, like this:

```
        <c:forEach items="${agents}" var="agent">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value=""/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${agent.phone}"/></td>
                <td><a href="${newMonthlyUrl}/${agent.guid}"><i class="icon-plus"></i> New Monthly</a></td>
                <td><a href="${editUrl}/${agent.guid}"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="${deleteUrl}/${agent.guid}"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Everything works fine on the source server.

Maven 2.2.1 
Tomcat 7.0.26, Java 7 on the source (compiled at Java 1.6 level)
Tomcat 7.0.37, Java 6 on the target

Any ideas why this would happen? What is changing the JSP file? I have verified that the correct source is making it through to the cloned repository. I'm perplexed!

Comment: What if you add `${agent.name}` and build again? and What if change the `${agent.name}` to other e.g. `${agentxx.name}`?

Comment: @Charlee, good ideas. I tried both, and in both cases, ${agentx.name} still gets wiped out.

Comment: Do you have any additional maven plugin other than maven war plugin?

Comment: Where are your jsp files located ?

Comment: jsp files are located under WebContent/WEB-INF/views, and the maven web app plugin has been told to use that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what happened here. But this is basically what I did, and the problem no longer exists:

1. Upgraded Maven 2.2.1 to 3.0.5
2. Upgraded Java 6 to Java 7
3. Declared a version in the maven web app plugin (v 2.3)
4. Rebuilt maven index
5. Fresh git push

Thanks to the commenters for chipping in.